# jQuery stop function from running on page load with .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple piece of code that seems to want to run as soon as the page loads.

```
$('.delete-product').each(function(event){ $(this).click( confDel(event) ); });

function confDel(event){
        var p = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
        if(!p){event.preventDefault(); }
    }
```

It's not supposed to run until the click event is triggered but as soon as the page loads, it immediately prompts me. If I write the script with an anonymous function, it doesn't seem to have an issue, but I'd rather write the function once and call it.

Thoughts?

Comment: in jQuery you are NOT suppose to use .each for things that do so automatically... http://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: As an alternative: `$('.delete-product').on('click', confDel);`

Comment: I wasn't sure considering that I would be adding an event handler to multiple nodes. Thanks for answering that thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need the `.each`.

Also, you need to give a function reference. When adding `()`, you transform the reference into a function call. That's why it is being called on page load.

That is enough :

```
$('.delete-product').click(confDel)
```

Comment: Yes this gets rid of the problem with the page load, but then the purpose of the function is lost because we're not passing the event to the function. http://jsfiddle.net/n9N7r/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/n9N7r/1/

Comment: @Sparatan117 The event is passed by default to the function, but `preventDefault()` doesnt do what you think it is doing. `preventDefault` is preventing the default behavior of the clicked element. Example : If you click on an `a` and prevent default, you will not be redirecting to the link. If you want to stop the function from running, you need to use `return false`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but you realize that in your example, the pop event happens whether preventDefault is commented out or not.

Comment: I retract my prior statement. For some reason, the function is now working as it should in the second example for no reason. 

I appreciate the help never the less

Comment: @Sparatan117 it never *work for no reason*. As for my example, i was showing you that prevent default wasnt cancelling the pop up (the text in the pop up is saying that aswell) but was cancelling the redirection of the link (page not going to google). To cancel a functio, use `return` : http://jsfiddle.net/n9N7r/4/